# The facebook php sdk in wamp is very slow

Tags: php, facebook, sdk, wamp

I develope an PHP facebook application with facebook PHP SDK, in a private server with wamp server 2.2.

My problem is: when I try to call

```
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
```

(of course in a `try {} catch {n block`) it responds about a 15-20 seconds. It is too slow, because while the page is loading nothing happens.

Is there anyone who's got a same problem? Or any solution?

Answer (score 0):

If it's that long you should check the network time. This sounds to me to more probably be the network then the script. If you use a linux based server you could use [Netstat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netstat) to give you an idea if the network is the problem.